# Java ArrayList a good way to access same list from many classes

Tags: java, arraylist, static

Hello i am trying to familiarize myself with Java by doing a very simple "bankaccount" application and it doesn't even save to db or something so it resets all data on rerun.

The problem i am trying to find a good way of doing is that i have an ArrayList of accounts that i want to be able to access from any class so that during runtime for example after an deposit if i access that account later when i want to get balance i get an that account from the ArrayList and it is updated to the deposit value.

When googling i found this solution but i dont like it since it uses static ArrayList. is there any more elegant way than this for an applicaiton that only saves the state/data during runtime.

Simple class that adds the test accounts and so on where first value is acountId and second is balance

```
public class AccountsModel {

private ArrayList<AccountModel> listOfAccounts;

public AccountsModel() {
    listOfAccounts = new ArrayList<AccountModel>();
    listOfAccounts.add(new AccountModel(1,0));
    listOfAccounts.add(new AccountModel(2,0));
    listOfAccounts.add(new AccountModel(3,0));
    listOfAccounts.add(new AccountModel(4,0));
}

 public ArrayList<AccountModel> getListOfAccounts(){
    return listOfAccounts;
 }
}
```

Then in my main class i just do this

```
static AccountsModel accounts = new AccountsModel();
public static ArrayList<AccountModel> listOfAccounts = accounts.getListOfAccounts();
```

this "works" as i can get the same list from anywhere within the application. But is there any simple and elegant way of doing this some other way?

Comment: You need to read a bit about different models of concurrency control. The implementation is secondary to that. That is, if you intend to make any read/write operations.

Comment: Maybe a singleton class? And maybe it would be better with a Map rather than a list so you can access a specific account using a unique key.

Comment: Unrelated: be careful about names that are typographically "close". Account**s**Model can very easily be misread for AccountModel. Avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you dislike the static solution but to me "It needs to be accessed by many classes" screams static variables.

Basically, you create a wrapper for your ArrayList which carries out operations:

```
class AccountsModel {
    private static ArrayList<AccountModel> singleton;

    // a static constructor also wouldn't be a bad idea here
    public static void init() {
        /* add a bunch of AccountModels here*/
    }

    public static ArrayList<AccountModel> getAccounts() {
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

An example of a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<AccountModel> accounts = AccountModels.getAccounts();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a better name than `getSingleton` since this solution has nothing to with the singleton pattern, something like `getAccounts` perhaps.

Comment: Yeah i like this more since it looks better like this than like i had it. Thanks i will use it